# When to hit the database instead of searching an object in your List

Tags: java, database, algorithm

If we are using MongoDB (NoSQL) or MySQL (Relational DB) to retrieve objects and we want to search for a specific element (where clause) but we already have an in-memory list (LinkedList, ArrayList or whatever) containing some of the Objects, either for caching or for any other reason.

Is there an equation / library that can "advice" when is cheaper to use the in-memory structure for retrieval instead of querying the Database? (taking into consideration,for example, the size of the in-memory list?)

Comment: Storing the data in the map makes things much quicker, where possible.

Comment: Yes I agree but at some point, I suppose it will be cheaper to query the database.

Comment: I doubt it. Querying in memory objects will be quicker in almost every possible use case. So many use cases, in fact, that I doubt you'll see a notable increase in performance.

Comment: I cannot think of a scenario where hitting the disk is going to be faster than reading the memory. The only possible reason you would like to hit the disk is if your cache is outdate, and needs to be refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always cheaper to query the in-memory cache.

The only exception would be if you had constructed the cache so that it was very inefficient to search it (e.g., linear search). But as long as it's a hash-based structure, it'll be doing at worst what the database needs to do, but without the network overhead. Looking something up in a hash table is essentially free.

The bigger question is whether your cache uses so much memory it starves the rest of the application. You'll want a weak hash map or similar, to avoid this. If this is a cache produced by some sort of ORM, it'll be weakly referenced already.

Comment: Even if it contains millions of objects and without index?

Comment: @salamis if it's a hash table of some sort, yes.

Comment: But if it IS in a hash table, it had an index. @salamis is making the point that the data structure he has available does not have an index.

Comment: If I have a person object with name, surname, date of birth, id it is better to create a hash table with index the combination of name, surname, id for example? and query the hashtable instead of querying the database?

Comment: IF you are able to reproduce the same key without querying the database again, then yes.

Comment: @chiastic-security I totally agree with your answer. However, why not just give the cache handling completely to something like EHCache in java and just forget auf maintaining the cache in the application?

Comment: @MatthiasSteinbauer yes I am going to use EHCache